# TFS 2015 Build: NuGet restore from an internal repository

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package, tfs-2015

We have set up an internal NuGet server and added that server into the package manager settings to publish our dependencies to our local dev machines.  Now we want to use the new TFS 2015 Build system to build our solution.

at the start of the build NuGet.exe restore is called passing in the solution file as seen in the log file:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Build\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe` restore "D:\TfsData\Build\_work\a8a26a03\Source Code...etc\mySolution.sln" -NonInteractive
```

next line in the log is the error

```
##[error]Unable to find version '1.0.0.5' of package 'com.bmico.models.lookup'
```

Which is a package on my internal server?

How do I tell TFS Build 2015 to use my internal package repository as well as the publicly available one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In root of your repository add file 'nuget.config'

and content of file like where you use nuget.org and network share where you have your's nuget fiels.

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="YoursNuGet" value="\\YourServerNugetShare\YourNuGets" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Should I not put this config file inside the directory where MSBuild calls NuGet.exe?

Comment: Nuget.config file suppose to be on root level of you code repository.

Comment: this solves our problem, thanks!

Comment: I tried this and it still did not work. Adding it to the root of the repo that is along with a git ignore. I also tried adding it to the build server under %ProgramData%\NuGet\Config\Nuget.config that didnt work either, any ideas?

Comment: Be sure to have access to network share and also use latest nugget manager version in visual studio.

Comment: @DanielSteenwyk is it working for you ?

Comment: @JanuszNowak yes. Forgot to accept answer.  Thanks